# CryptographicException on SaveAllState()

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mschart

I have an ASP.net app that is loading a page and displaying a chart using data from a SQL query. I can run the page on the deployment server but anyone who isn't a machine admin appears to hit this exception:

```
[CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.]
System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input) +246
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +444
System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +67
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save() +175
System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() +1158
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4860
```

I'm not really sure what is failing to serialize for users other than myself. In remote debug sessions I can see that we can run everything in the aspx page load and then we throw an exception. For the users that are failing they are in a security group on the test server with full privileges on the web root.

Comment: Also, I am using EntityFramework for the database model